# shelljs - getting process ID of process created by shelljs.exec() process

Tags: javascript, node.js, shelljs

So, I'm dealing with an issue on Windows where I can't kill a process spawned using shell.exec(...).

I'm creating the process like this:

```
const shell = require('shelljs');

// ...

let childProcess = shell.exec('someBinary --whatever', { async: true });
```

And then trying to kill it like this:

```
childProcess.kill();
```

Which works on *nix but not on Windows (for some reason).

Therefore, I'm trying to get the process ID of the process ('someBinary --whatever') created by the shell.exec() process, and using that to kill the process at some later time.

It's trivial to get the PID of the shell.exec() process, but I can't work out how to get the PID of the process it spawns.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [taskkill](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx) with parameter `/t` to terminate all child processes along with the parent process, commonly known as a tree kill.

Comment: Legend.
Cheers mate

Comment: Sorry @stdof-- I got caught up implementing the solution